# What is the most efficient/user friendly way to send multiple variables to different functions every time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have lots of variables, some pickled files that I load at the beginning of the code and many functions. Since all the main algorithm is carried out inside the functions (which are multiple nested functions), I find very unpractical sending 10-15 variables & pickle loaded constants to those functions at every time I need to execute a function.

Below I only put 5 pickle loaded constants (actually there are 11 of them in actual code) and some variables teta_ls, phi_ls, k, N, ti, fi,anm_offline

So, I believe there should be a way much more pythonic and practical for passing 16-17 arguments to the functions I use

```
file = open("spherical_jn_der_offline","rb")
spherical_jn_der_offline = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

file = open("spherical_jn_offline","rb")
spherical_jn_offline = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

file = open("sph_harm_offline","rb")
sph_harm_offline = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

file = open("spherical_bn_offline","rb")
spherical_bn_offline = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

file = open("sph_harm_offline_der","rb")
sph_harm_offline_der = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

def interpolation(N, k, ti, fi,anm_offline,spherical_jn_der_offline,spherical_jn_offline,sph_harm_offline,spherical_bn_offline),sph_harm_offline_der):

        p_grad = grad(teta_ls, phi_ls, k, N, ti, fi,anm_offline,spherical_jn_der_offline,spherical_jn_offline,sph_harm_offline,spherical_bn_offline),sph_harm_offline_der) 
        u = calc_u(p_grad, ro, k, f[fi])  
        p = pressure_field(fi, ti, N,anm_offline,spherical_jn_der_offline,spherical_jn_offline,sph_harm_offline,spherical_bn_offline),sph_harm_offline_der)  
        I_act, In = ia(p, u)    

        return(p,I_act)

for ti in range(23350):
    for fi in range(257):
pressure_ls, I_ls = interpolation(N, k, ti, fi, anm_offline,spherical_jn_der_offline,spherical_jn_offline,sph_harm_offline,spherical_bn_offline),sph_harm_offline_der)
```

My question is not specific-code related, that is why I didn't provide any variable "values" etc. I am asking in terms of "writing better codes", I am actually a mechanical engineer very new to "code organization/structure"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open your files in a loop:

```py
files = ["spherical_jn_der_offline", "spherical_jn_offline"] # etc....
arguments = []

for file in files:
    fd = open(file,"rb")
    arguments.append(pickle.load(file))
    fd.close()
```

Then you could unpack the `arguments` list to the function:

```py
for ti in range(23350):
    for fi in range(257):
        pressure_ls, I_ls = interpolation(N, k, ti, fi, anm_offline, *arguments)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pack them into a dict with keys being argument names and **kwargs unpack them in the function call